# Change classname attribute of a div in a component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a card-publication component and I want to be able to make the component reusable and when declaring the tag I can also declare its classname and the position to place it in.

Component and main code.

```
import React from 'react';

function CardPublication({name}) {
    return (
        <div id={name}>
            <div id="Card Incard">

            </div>
            <p id="Descripcion"> Paragraph .</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CardPublication
```

and how should I declare them.

```
<CardPublication ></CardPublication>
<CardPublication ></CardPublication>
```

Comment: Why not pass `classes` in as you would any other prop? I'm not clear on your issue.

Comment: Also, use self-closing syntax for your components: `<CardPublication/>`

Comment: The `id` attribute for any HTML tag must be unique in the document.  That's how you identify them.  You can't use `"Card Incard"` and `"Descripcion"` repeatedly.

Comment: You rarely need IDs in a React app. Here you can probably switch them to classes if they're just for styling.

Comment: Mauro Arteaga, you might explain what you're doing with the classes. There may be better solutions than passing them in. Beware of [XY questions](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parsing the props from your declaration components to the component, there is an explain of your case. You must set the arguments on your component first

```
import React from 'react';

function CardPublication({props}) {
    return (
        <div className={props.name}>
            <div id="Card Incard">

            </div>
            <p id="Descripcion"> Paragraph .</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CardPublication
```

And then you can declaration your component with props and value that you want

```
<CardPublication name="cards1"></CardPublication>
<CardPublication name="cards2"></CardPublication>
```

So, the name props will parsing the argument to your component. And you will have two div with "cards1" class and "cards2" class.

You also can learn about components and props on https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html